# Pagination for Rails Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

What can I use for Pagination in Rails 4.0?

I need it for a mobile website and I am using Jquery Mobile too.

I am using Kaminari in my desktop website, but it fails to run correctly with mobile website. If I use it with my mobile website it is overriding the mobile format to html format.

Comment: Can you explain what's the issue in mobile?

Comment: I am detecting if the request is coming form mobile. If it does, I am changing the format of pages rendered to .mobile.erb as per the tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

But, when I use pagination via kaminari, it is overriding the format of pages and rendering .html.erb

Comment: That tutorial is 5 years old :). Which rails version are you using? If it's rails 4.1 then it includes [`variants`](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/) which will help you achieve what you are looking for. I'll also recommend you to checkout [`bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/) which will dry up your code and reduce duplicate html